# How to add items to strings in a list in python

Tags: python, list, loops, iterator, append

This is my code:

```
t=['']*20
slist=s1.split()
for i in range(20):
    j=math.floor(random()*10)
    for k in range(5):
        t[i]=(slist[j])
    print(t[i])
```

Basically `t[i]` is a list with a word in it and I want to add 5 random words from `slist` to `t[i]`. With just the equal sign it overwrites the word.
Also `+=` or `append` doesn't seem to work in list. I know there are better methods out there but i wanna see if it can be done like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that strings are immutable.

```
t=['']*20
slist=s1.split()
for i in range(20):
    j=math.floor(random()*10)
    for k in range(5):
        t[i]= t[i] + slist[j]
    print(t[i])
```

Just use + and reassign the returned string.